# How to render errors pages in Flask not causing errors loop from requested blueprint?

Tags: templates, flask, error-handling

I have a problem that my Flask error handling procedure renders templates within the context of the blueprint where error occurred.
I need an advice for better architecture or how to properly omit the problem.

The simplified layout of my flask app is as follows:

```sh
app/
    errors/
        templates/
            errors/
                500.html
    handlers.py

    sales/
        templates/
        __init__.py
```

In the `salse/__init__.py` there are `@bp.contex_processor` for injecting the `cart` object to make it availbable in all `sales/templates/` (simmilary as typical `current_user`):

```py
salse/__init__.py

@bp.context_processor
def inject_cart():
    return dict(cart = cli.request('https://1.1.1.1/cart/load))
```

```py
handler.py

@bp.app_errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

The cart is loaded from a foreign system.

The problem is with connection error handling to the foreign system.

#### Desired scenario

1. User was not working for a long time - the foreign system closed the connection.
2. User is clicking something
3. In the foreign system connection package, there is an Exception 'Authorization expired for the user'
4. Flask catches the error and renders the `errors/500.html` which asks the user to log in again (and also do the authorization to the foreign system in the background).

#### Current scenario

1. as above
2. as above
3. as above
4. Flask catches the error and is calling `render_template(errors/500.html)`
5. Inside the `render_template('errors/500.html')` the `flask.app.Flask#update_template_context()` checks that request blueprint (`reqctx.request.blueprint`) is the `sales` and finally is executing the `inject_cart()`
6. `inject_cart():` is trying to request foreign system, but the connection is closed so the error from 3. occurs again......
7. Finally, Flask is showing it's built-in "Server error" page.

I think that it is not good, that error handling is not separated from the blueprint where error occurred causing errors flood.

But do you have a proposal for better application structure to omit this problem? Or maybe I should not use `render_template()` for handling error templates?

For now I just used the `redirect()` instead of `render_template()`. But I feel that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Flask app is defined in `app/__init__.py`, I think you're templates structure should be

```
app/
    templates/
        errors/
            500.html
    handlers.py

    sales/
        templates/
        __init__.py
```

That is unless you're specyfing your template folder on app/blueprint initialization. See `help(flask.Flask)`

````
:param template_folder: the folder that contains the templates that should
                        be used by the application.  Defaults to
                        ``'templates'`` folder in the root path of the
                        application.```
````

EDIT: To add clarity

You can override module templates in your app's main template directory. You cannot override your app's main templates in a module (without leveraging some underlying jinja operations that is). Therefore, if your structure is like this:

```
app/
    templates/
        errors/
            500.html
    handlers.py

    sales/
        templates/
            errors/
                500.html
        __init__.py
```

A sales blueprint `app_errorhandler` will override your apps `errorhandler`, but trying to render `errors/500.html` will render `app/templates/errors/500.html`. I believe this is by design to allow overriding 3rd party module templates.

The best convention is to nest your module templates within the module name, such as a structure like this:

```
app/
    templates/
        errors/
            500.html
    handlers.py

    sales/
        templates/
            sales/
                errors/
                    500.html
        __init__.py
```

Then your sales blueprint can handle it's own 500 errors like so

```
@bp.app_errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    return render_template('sales/errors/500.html'), 500
```

Then if you really wanted or needed to you could override the sales module errors templates

```
app/
    templates/
        sales/
            errors/
                500.html
        errors/
            500.html
    handlers.py

    sales/
        templates/
            sales/
                errors/
                    500.html
        __init__.py
```

Comment: I moved the templates to the blueprint:

    bp = Blueprint('sales', __name__, template_folder='templates')

but it doesn't matter where the templates are, the problem is the same as I mentioned.

Comment: If you're looking to override the `errors/500.html` template for the `sales` blueprint, the template should exist at `sales/templates/errors/500.html`. You should then render with `return render_template('errors/500.html'), 500`.

Comment: My problem is not to have a dedicated `500.html` error page for the sales module, but to have one for the whole app `500.html` error page. The problem is if there is an Exception in the sales module `__init__.py`, then rendering the **global error/500.html** causes calling the again the sales/__init__.py, as it is requested blueprint. That makes the error avalanche.

Comment: I would try using `@app.errorhandler` instead of letting the blueprint handle it. That might avoid your `context_processor`. You might also be able to detect the 500 in your `inject_cart`. Lastly, you could make your session expire the same as the foreign system, making the user log back in before any error occurs.